# Xamarin Android Pop-up window

Tags: android, xamarin, popup

I used code from developer.xamarin site, but it does not work, i think that i miss some "using" files.

```
var alertButton2 = new Button { Text = "DisplayAlert Yes/No" }; // trigger alert
alertButton2.Clicked += async (sender, e) => {
var answer = await DisplayAlert ("Question?", "Would you like to play a game", "Yes", "No");
Debug.WriteLine("Answer: " + answer); // writes true or false to the console
```

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Don't add error as picture. Paste it in your question.

Comment: Can you add the link to the example you've used?

Comment: The code you are using is for Xamarin Forms.  Is that what you are using, or are you using Xamarin Android?  For Android popups, see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/popup_menus/